# I keep getting a compiler error whenever I try to use functions

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors

I'm learning C, and we have been recently been taught functions. User defined functions strike me as fascinating, and so I decided to write a simple program to try out how a function works. Here's my code:

```
#include"stdio.h"

int main()
{
    func();
}
func()
{
    printf("This program uses a function.");
}
```

I pressed "compile" and I got a compliler error. The exact message it gave me is:

```
fpermissive]
func()
^
Return code is not 0
```

The diagnostics do not imply a mistake in the code that I wrote, so I'm unable to find out where I made a mistake. Can someone help me fix this program, and also successfully learn how to use user defined functions?

**Edit:**

I had forgotten to mention the return type of the function. I did that now, and here's my modified code:

```
#include"stdio.h"

int main()
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
int func()
{
    printf("This program uses a function.");
    return 0;
}
```

I pressed compile again, and got a different error message. This one says:

```
was not declared in this scope
func();
^
Return code is not 0
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the return type of your function `func()`? You need to mention that such as `void func()` or `int func()`

Comment: Okay, lemme fix that @AditiRawat

Comment: you need to declare `func()` before `main()`

Comment: Also you need to take care of forward declaration

Comment: You are using an incomplete function prototype.  Traditionally, this meant it returns an `int` and its arguments are unspecified, but you really shouldn't do that today.  If you don't want to return a value, then declare it void.  Similarly, if you don't want to pass any arguments, declare a void argument list.  I.e. `void func(void)`.  Finally, add a forward declaration for the function so that the compiler knows how to call it.  All of this should have been covered in your tutorial.

Comment: @TomKarzes Wonderful, thanks. You explained everything that I needed to know. Can you convert that comment into an answer so I can accept it as one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to study the syntax better. Your function doesn't return anything, so you need to put a void in front of the name. You also need to put a void between parenthesis of your functions. And move the function definition before the main, or, as other answers mention, add a function declaration before the use of the variable.

A function declaration is composed by:

1. the optional keyword `extern`
2. the first line of the function, i.e. the type returned, the name, parameters between parenthesis
3. a semicolon

In your case: `extern void func(void);`, or simply `void func(void);`.

Comment: *"And move the function definition before the main."* Ahh I had been thinking about that for quite a while. My CS teacher put the function definition after the main(), so I had thought we could do it after as well. Anyway, thanks for patching this up.

Comment: Or add a forward declaration, which is a good idea in general.  You don't need to move the definition.

Comment: My personal preference for students is to start by saying that what you use has to be defined before its use. After some practice than introduce declarations.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take care of two things: (a) Declaring `func()` before `main()` , (b) mentioning the return type of `func()`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void func(void); //forward declaration

int main()
{
    func();
}
void func(void) //specifying return type as **void**
{
    printf("This program uses a function.");
}
```

Comment: You forgot to declare a void argument list. Bad practice. These are not variadic functions.

Comment: Also, it is better to use <stdio.h>, not "stdio.h"

Comment: @TomKarzes Can you explain why <stdio.h> is preferred over "stdio.h"? I'm on my Android phone using CPPDroid, and reaching the "<" and ">" symbols is harder than quotations.

Comment: The argument lists are still wrong.  They are improperly declared.

Comment: Using `<>` in an include causes the preprocessor to search only the include path, and not the source directory.  So you use `<>` when including external header files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845415/what-is-the-difference-between-stdio-h-and-stdio-h

Comment: Making progress, but forward decl and your function decl need to match (use `void` for both arg lists).

Answer (score 1):

The error occurred because the compiler didn't encounter any function named

```
func();
```

when it entered the main function. You need to, atleast, declare a function if not writing its body.

So, you have to do declare a function before main if you wan to write its code after main()

Answer (score 0):

You are missing return type of func(). Please look at syntax of way of defining functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include"stdio.h"

void func();  // Forward declare func() here.

int main()
{
    func();
}

void func() // Ensure func() has a return type 'void'
{
    printf("This program uses a function.");
}
```

Comment: You forgot to declare a `void` argument list.  Bad practice.  These are not variadic functions.

Comment: Also, it is better to use `<stdio.h>`, not `"stdio.h"`

Comment: @TomKarzes Those coding practice improvements do not help the OP answer the original question.  They are extra noise for this case.

Comment: The `stdio` problem perhaps, but not the function prototype.  That is OP's entire problem, so a correct prototype should be given in any answer.